# At what age an infant can start flying?

Tags: air-travel, health, airlines, regulations, children

Can a month old infant fly? Are there any health related issues prevent that or is it ok? Any restrictions from airlines I may face?

Comment: Infants do not all grow their feathers and wings at the same rate. Rather than going by age alone, test their abilities while attached to a string with a well-cushioned floor beneath them.

Comment: @hippietrail hahahahahahahaha

Comment: I can tell you that I flew form London to Munich when I was only 3 days old. So far (40 years later), I cannot tell you that I have any issues, or at least none that I could trace back to being originated on that flight.

Comment: All my three kids took their first flight between 2 and 3 months of age. No issues at all (make sure you book the flight early enough so you still get a baby bed, if possible, though).

Comment: could you please be more specific? which country for example?

Answer (score 4):

There are recommendations from [Pediatricians](http://www.babycenter.com/404_at-what-age-is-it-safe-for-my-baby-to-fly_7258.bc) that state the child should be 2 to 3 months old before traveling on an airplane.  There is ample evidence in the same link that it could be safe enough for even a younger child to travel and a confirmation of this from [Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/air-travel-with-infant/HQ00197).  However, it is up to the individual airline to set the policy on how young is too young.

For example, [United](http://www.united.com/web/en-US/Content/travel/specialneeds/infants/default.aspx) won't accept

> infants in incubators or infants younger than seven days old.

But [US Air](http://www.usairways.com/en-US/traveltools/specialneeds/children.html) doesn't impose such a restriction.

As far as health issues are concerned you should be concerned with 2 major ones change of pressure during takeoff and landing, babies don't know how to deal with it so you will get crying.  And second being that child's immune system is not as developed as the adult one, so he/she might catch something that someone else is carrying that you might be immune to.

Answer (score 2):

The last question will depend on your airline.  But for instance, United Airlines [says](http://www.united.com/web/en-US/Content/travel/specialneeds/infants/default.aspx) infants younger than seven days old may not travel, implying that infants older than seven days are generally permitted.